# ¿Por que no puedo pintar todo el botón de rojo?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

¿Cómo puedo pintar el background de rojo en un botón en python utilizando `ttk`?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.title('test')
        self.master.geometry('600x375')

        self.s = ttk.Style(self)
        self.s.configure('TButton', background='red')
        self.test = ttk.Button(self.master, text='prueba', style='TButton')
        self.test.pack(padx=50, pady=20)

main = App()
main.mainloop()
```

He intentado con `.map` pero ocurre lo mismo, sólo cambia el contorno.

```
self.s.map('option.TButton', background=[('active','red'), ('focus','red') ])
```

Y todo el código esta igual a excepción del estilo del botón cuando lo intento con `map`.

```
self.test = ttk.Button(self.master, text='prueba', style='TButton')
```

¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar el color de fondo para que el botón sea rojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Aunque no es tan simple como cuando se utilizan los botones con `Tk`, es posible si se configura un tema (`theme_use`) con cualquiera de las siguientes opciones: 'winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative'.

Ejemplo utilizando el tema `alt`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.title('test')
        self.master.geometry('600x375')

        self.s = ttk.Style(self)
        self.s.theme_use('alt')
        self.s.configure('TButton', background='red')
        self.test = ttk.Button(self.master, text='prueba', style='TButton')
        self.test.pack(padx=50, pady=20)

main = App()
main.mainloop()
```

Esto crea la siguiente ventana:

[image: Ventana con botón rojo]